# How many bytes does a BigQuery Date require

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got a timestamp column in BigQuery, and now I realize I could have used a date data type to represent this column instead (I don't need fine time granularity).  My table is large and expensive to query so I'm wondering whether I'll save money by converting it to a new column of type DATE instead.

However, [the official BigQuery documentation on data types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#date-type) doesn't seem to indicate how many bytes a date object requires.  Does anyone here know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE and TIMESTAMP both require 8 bytes

You can see more details at [`Data size calculation`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data)

Comment: Thanks! That's too bad, considering it could be represented in just 3 bytes (the valid domain of dates is [0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31], or about 3.65 million days.  I was hoping it would be just 4 bytes.  Looks like BigQuery doesn't have any 4 byte data types though so maybe it keeps the backend simpler to keep most types 8 bytes.